# BS4: Get lxml etree from BeautifulSoup object

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

If I use BeautifulSoup4 with the `lxml` parser, how can I get the lxml etree object from a BeautifulSoup object?

I would use it to find elements by XPath. BeautifulSoup4 does not support XPath itself

Comment: why not use lxml directly?

Comment: Because I already have the scraper written BeautifulSoup and I won't re-write all those lines of code just for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lxml_root = etree.fromstring(str(soup).encode())
```